# Colors in filtered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, filter, color-swatches, filtered-nav

I setted the Colors attribute in the filtered navigation. If a search a product, all the colors are shown but when I click on a single color, for example "blue", the "blue" products aren't shown and are shown all the configurable product that have an associated product in blue colore. To explain well, I attach some screenshots.

[image: The colors appears and I click on blue]

[image: This is the result]

Answer (score 0):

Those 4 backpacks are displaying when you filter by "blue" because you have assigned them the color "blue" on the configurable product and/or simple products.

If you have a configurable backpack with four colors, make sure the configurable product **does not** have any color assigned and assign respective colors to the the simple products.